# ajax success method not showing data in asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working on as asp.net application. Its view has a button like this:

```
<input type="button" id="btnCall" title="Call" value="Call" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" />
```

and in document.ready, I have this:

```
$("#btnCall").click(function () {
    alert("here");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text/json",
        url: "/account/getGenericPassword",
        success: function (data) {                   
            alert("data" + data);
            if (data == null || data == "") {
                 alert("Generic Password is empty. Please enter generic password");
            }
            else {
               //saveCallRecording();
            }
       }
   });
});
```

and method is like this:

```
[Authorize]
public JsonResult GetGenericPassword() {
     using (IUserProfileManager profilemanager = new ManagerFactory().GetUserProfileManager())            {
          UserProfile profile = profilemanager.GetProfile(CurrentUser.Id, CurrentAccount.Id);
          return Json(profile.GenericPassword == null ? "" : profile.GenericPassword, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
}
```

but alert in success is not shown. Please suggest solution.

Comment: Use the dev tools in your browser to set breakpoints, and watch AJAX traffic. At what point is it failing? Is your click handler getting hit? Is the server getting hit?

Comment: yes server side gets hit but nothing is shown as alert on browser

Comment: there is case sensivity about here `/account/getGenericPassword` check this line. I sugges use `@Url.Action("action","controller")`

Comment: If you use the browser debug tools (F12) what is it returning? It sounds like it might not be a 200 code, so success is not being called. As an aside, you are making a call using POST, so you can remove JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the dataType like so:

```
dataType: "json"
```

See the valid dataType options at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

try with these

type:'Post',
url:'@Url.Action("actionname","controller")',
datatype:"json",
data:{},
success:function(data){
}